# Send data via post to action create Jquery and Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I am using Jquery. I have created a array javasript called @provinces in localhost:3000/provinces/new. I need pass that array to localhost/provinces through the POST method, I mean to the create action
I created a special button for that called Send data via post

```
<html>
<head>
  <title></title>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script>
   $(document).ready(function(){
     $provinces=new Array();

  $(".add").click(function(e) {

    $("body").append("<label class='label1'>Add Province</label>");
    $("body").append("<input type='text' class='value'/>")
    $(".add").prop('disabled', true);
    $("body").append("<input type='button' id='save' value='Save'>")    
   });
   $("body").on("click","#save", function(){
        $provinces.push($(".value").val());
        $(".label1").remove();
        $(".value").remove();
        $(".add").prop('disabled', false);
        $(this).remove();        
     });
   $("body").on("click",".show", function(){
      $cadena="";   
         for($i=0;$i<$provinces.length;$i++){
            $cadena=$cadena+"\n"+$provinces[$i];
         }
         alert($cadena);
   });
   $("body").on("click",".send", function(){

   });
  });

  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <h1>New province</h1>
  <button class="add">Add Province</button>
  <button class="show">Show array</button>  
  <button class="send">SendData via post</button>
  <br/><br/>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: build a form and submit to the create action! In your routing table you should have a url for it! submit the form there!

Comment: What happens is that the array is written in Javascript

Answer (score 1):

Examine this line:

```
$provinces=new Array();
```

1) In js, the $ sign has no special meaning when used like that.  In fact, the $ sign is sometimes used in jQuery to indicate that a variable has been assigned a *wrapped set*, and your array is not a wrapped set, so the $ sign is misleading.

2) `new Array()` is equivalent to `[]`, so you can simply write:

```
var provinces = [];
```

You cannot pass arrays between javascript and ruby code(or vice versa).  However, you can use  javascript to send a request that contains a string to a ruby program on the server.

1) You can convert your array to a string using:

```
JSON.stringify()
```

2) You can send a string to a ruby program on the server using jQuery's `.ajax()` function:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/provinces/create',
    type: 'POST',
    contentType: 'application/json',
    data: json_str
})
.success(function(resp_data, text_status) {
  console.log('resp: ' + resp_data);
  console.log('status: ' + text_status);
})
.fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
  console.log('status: ' + textStatus);
  console.log('error: ' + errorThrown);
})
```

3) On the server side, if a request has a Content-Type equal to 'application/json', Rails will automatically parse the body of a request(your json_str) into ruby Arrays and Hashes, which Rails makes available in the params hash.   The array will be available as `params['_json']` or `params[provinces]['_json]`.

If you don't like having to look for your array under the '_json' key in the rails params hash, then in your js code you can convert your array to an object, like this:

```
var provinces = [];
...
var obj =  {my_array: provinces};
var json_str = JSON.stringify(obj);
```

Then in your ruby code, the array will be available as `params[my_array]` or `params[provinces][my_array]`.

Comment: Thanks. The problem is that the method create redirects a show.html.erb. I need pass that array to method create and then create redirects a show. I don't need to see the results in the same page Therefore no use ajax

Comment: @danielbarrera, *I don't need to see the results in the same page Therefore no use ajax*--But you do need to send a string representation of the array to the server, and because there is no form on your page, you have to use ajax.  The fact that create() redirects to show() is irrelevant.